# Multiple for comprehensions within a map in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is the function,

```
def checkSupport(request: checkSupportRequest): Future[checkSupportResponse] = {
  val lookupClient = Thrift.newIface[lookupClient[Future]](/*some initializers*/)
  val req = lookupIPRequest(request.getIps, /*Unimportant variables*/)
  var result = new checkSupportResponse()

  lookupClient.performLookup(req).map { resp =>
    // Returns a map of IP to Country Code (String:String)
    val ip_cc_map = for {
      (ip, lxn) <- resp.found
       sr <- lxn.simpleResult
      cc <- sr.countryCode
    } yield (ip, cc)
     // Returns a map of IP to Boolean (String:Boolean)
    val not_found_map = for {
      (ip) <- resp.notFound
    } yield (ip, false)

    val op_supp_temp_map = ip_cc_map.map {
      case (ip, cc) => someLookup(cc) //This returns a boolean value 
    }
    val op_supp_map = op_supp_temp_map.toList //List of Booleans
    val ips_found = ip_cc_map.map { // Intended to become a list of IPs
      case (ip, cc) => ip
    }
    val final_op_supp_map = ips_found zip op_supp_map // Converted to Map (String:Boolean)

    final_map = final_op_supp_map ++ not_found_map

    result.set_supported(final_result.toList.toMap.mapValues(Boolean.box))
  }
  Future.value(result)
}
```

The performLookup is a futurized call. Is it kosher to do things as above i.e. take the output of the futurized call and map it. Perform two back-to-back for comprehensions on it to obtain the necessary maps and then subsequently in the same for, combine the two results and return the same. For some reason, this compiles but when I'm trying to unit-test it, it appears as if the performLookup never ran. Any help would be appreciated.

Also I am in my unit-test doing an Await.result() on the checkSupport() call.

Comment: If your performLookup function returns a `Future`, then your `checkSupport` function returns a `Future[Result]`, not a `Result`. Your `checkSupport` method definition is missing an `=` sign, your `for` comprehension seems to use map on things that are not mappable (`level_2_variable`, `country_code`) although I can't be 100% sure because your object definitions are incomplete (missing types, `val`, `def` keywords), and look much more like Java than Scala. Please post a version of your code that actually compiles and it'll be easier to help, although your problem is likely what @som-snytt said.

Comment: @som-snytt - I am doing an Await.result() within my Unit test code. Thanks for the reminder though :)

Comment: @noziar - I was trying to be as generic as possible. I've modified the code to be more obvious. I believe things are compatible. For some reason, the failure I see in my unit tests is,

'checkSupportResponse()' is not the same as 'checkSupportResponse(supported:{21.255.255.254=true})'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `Future.value(result)` you actually mean `Future.successful(result)`.

The `result` variable inside the closure is different from the `result` variable outside of it, so you're never actually modifying the `result` variable that you're declaring at the beginning of your function. So this is why it looks like your `Future` never ran.

As a side-note, even if you mutate the state of `result`, you don't need to declare it as `var`, `val` is good here (`var` would only be necessary if you were reassigning it by doing `result = ...`).

So you can modify your function like this:

```
def checkSupport(request: checkSupportRequest): Future[checkSupportResponse] = {
    // declare lookupClient and req as before, but not res

    lookupClient.performLookup(req).map { resp =>
        // do all your processing like before

        val result = new checkSupportResponse()
        result.setOperator_supported(final_result.toList.toMap.mapValues(Boolean.box))

        // We want "result" to be the result of the computation
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaah that was a typo. The result in the closure is actually commented out in my code but after copying it over, I removed the comment. I changed it to Future.successful() instead of Future.result() but it could not find successful() as a member of Future....I somehow wondering if the mocking of the internal APIs might be the problem as part of my unit tests....Or could there be something still wrong in code?

Comment: You need to remove the `Future.successful` altogether or you will have a race condition. `performLookup` already returns a Future. Then you transform this Future using `map`, and this is it: the last expression in your code block will be what is returned by the function. If you add `Future.successful(...)` after that, then it is as if you completely ignored the previous one, and just return a trivial Future that resolves immediately, without waiting for the computation you care about to finish.

Comment: So I changed the code as you suggested i.e. as above and having removed the Future.value() call all-together at the end. That does compile but it completely ends up breaking my unit test. It fails as below,

org.specs.runner.UserError: com.company_name.NoBrokersAvailableException: No hosts are available for client thrift at com.company_name.NoStacktrace(Unknown Source)

Comment: Good news! It probably means that now your Future is actually being run :) Now your Scala problem is solved, the exception that you have with your unit test is specific to your codebase and probably doesn't belong to this discussion. I guess something is happening inside your `performCheck` or `someLookup` functions that makes the runtime unhappy.

Comment: You're awesome. That along with some modifications on the Unit test side fixed my issue. Thanks for being patient and helping out!